# Is there any way to programmatically set the comment attribute on a file in XP?

Tags: c++, windows-xp

Links to point me in the correct direction, or sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with some unmanaged calls, check the OLE32 function StgOpenPropStg() and StgOpenStorageEx() functions at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380342(VS.85).aspx

There's quite a bit to this but the function name should get you going.